# JsPath: navigate backward

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

let me explain the problem that I'm facing:

I have two JSON objects, let's call them **js1** and **js2**, I need to update **js1** using "parts" of **js2** object, and to do that I need to identify where this parts that needs to be updated are in **js1**.

To do that, I'm using a function that, for a certain input, return the full *JsPath* from root to the input value, and I get back a *JsPath* like this:

```
/priceLists(1)/sections(0)/items(0)(0)/itemIdentifier
```

what I need to do is navigate backward one step, to obtain a *JsPath* like

```
/priceLists(1)/sections(0)/items(0)(0)
```

I'm probably very dumb (and with not so much experience with Scala in general) but I can't find any way to do that.

The only way I found to get rid of that last part of the path is to transform *JsPath* into a list of *PathNode*, but then I don't know how to transform back that list of *PathNodes* into a *JsPath*.

I'm using Play 2.6 and Scala 2.11.8.

Comment: Try `path.copy(path = path.dropRight(1))`

Comment: path.copy(path = path.path.dropRight(1)) thanks @cchantep !